# Change tab layout tab color?

Tags: java, android, android-tabhost

Im Creating an android studio app , i want when user clicked on a  tab button the tab icon/color

change this is my code :

```
       tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

               int id= tabHost.getCurrentTab();
              //  TabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(int color); // Error because of non static method

//                if(id==0){
//                    TabHost.TabSpec tab1spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("List");
//                    tab1spec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home2));
//                }
//                if(id==1){
//                    TabHost.TabSpec tab1spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Config");
//                    tab1spec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lab2));
//                }
//                if(id==2){
//                    TabHost.TabSpec tab1spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("More");
//                    tab1spec.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.more2));
//                }

            }
        });
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener(){
              @Override 
              public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
                int tab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tab).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                setTabColor(tabHost);
              } 
            });        
    } 

    public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
        for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        { 
            tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); //unselected
        } 
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); // selected
}
```